# GNU GCC/LD : Which libraries are linked by default?

Tags: gcc, linker, default, libraries

I am a regular C programmer, and there's something I have wondered for some time about GNU GCC/LD internals.

I have noticed that, when passing a sequence of object files to GCC (e.g `gcc main.o otherfile.o`), GCC automatically links `libc.a` library file without my explicitly specifying `-lc` in the options. Similarly, when I compile a program using `ncurses`, I just need to specify `-lncurses` and `libtinfo.a` gets linked automatically (no need to specify `-ltinfo`). In other words, even though `ncurses` functions use functions from `libtinfo` (for instance, `unctrl()`), I don't need to explicitly link libtinfo.

How can it be possible?

Does GCC/LD have a list of "default libraries" where it looks for missing symbols when linking? If such a table exists, where is it and how can it be configured?

Answer (score 2):

A direct answer is that you can see what libraries are linked by command line options by adding `-v` to the linking command line.  This will show you the commands as they are executed.

The C library and the GCC support library or libraries are linked automatically; other libraries have to be specified manually.

The case of `-lncurses` and `libtinfo.a` (`libtinfo.so`?) is rather different.  There, the link command used to build `libncurses.so` tells the linker that this library also needs `-ltinfo`, so it automatically picks up the extra library.